# Move From UIView to View controller in button action

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have created a button in `UIView` class, which I want to move to another view controller. When I press the button, it should move to view controller.

I have this in `UIView` class:

```
[_okButton addTarget:self action:@selector(delete:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

-(IBAction):(id)sender
{
    SiteViewController *SiteVC2 = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil]instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SiteVC2"];    
}
```

Please help me to do this. Move From UIView to ViewController

Answer (score 0):

Can you please tell me where (i mean in which view controller) you are adding this UIView instance as sub view.

Option 1 : Need to write a delegate for your UIView sub class and implement the delegate in the viewcontroller. Now fire the delegate when button tapped from UIView subclass. On delegate call back in viewcontroller you can move to next viewcontroller(SiteViewController)

Option 2 :  Find the top most view controller by fetching visible view controller from navigation stack and push/present the desired viewcontroller (SiteViewController) on fetched viewcontroller.

If both are not fitting for your requirement get back to me we'll try in a couple of other available ways

Answer (score 0):

```
[_okButton addTarget:self action:@selector(delete:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

-(IBAction)delete:(id)sender{
 SiteViewController *SiteVC2 = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil]instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SiteVC2"];
}
//If you want to change the navigation Controller
-(IBAction)delete:(id)sender{    
SiteViewController * SiteVC2 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SiteVC2"];

UINavigationController *navigationController =
[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: SiteVC2];
[self presentViewController:navigationController
                   animated:NO
                 completion:^{

                 }];
    }
}
```